# getURL not working on HTML export (Actionscript2.0)

Tags: html, flash, button, actionscript

I was trying to add a facebook connection in developing flash website. Am using actionscript 2.0. 
I used the the following code more the button

```
on (release)
{
    getURL("http://www.facebook.com", "_blank");
}
```

button works and takes me to the facebook link in SWF export. But am not yet able to access the link from the exported HTML file.

(when i click the button in HTML export, it is connecting this link, file:///D:/WEBDESIGN/www.facebook.com)

It would be a great if someone can help me out to find the soluntion.

Thank you,
Yousuf.

Comment: You would get that result for getURL("www.facebook.com", "_blank"), without the HTTP protocol specified, but not for getURL("http://www.facebook.com", "_blank"). Are you sure the code you posted here is the same as when you get the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lars,

this is the code i put in script editor



on (release) {
 getURL("www.facebook.com", "_blank");
}



it is working  when press cntrl+enter, but not in the exported HTML file.

Comment: Again, you need to include the protocol, HTTP, so `getURL("http://www.facebook.com", "_blank")` should work, while `getURL("www.facebook.com", "_blank")` won't.

Comment: Lars, I tried and is still not working in the html export. :(

any refernce or examples u can share with? 
that would be of great help 
Thank you 
Yousuf.

Comment: Are you viewing this in a browser by opening an HTML file or by simply executing the swf from explorer?

Comment: Lars is absolutely right. Your described behavior indicates you did not start the URL with http:// and thus your URL is treated as relative. When you say it's still not working, what's the current behavior?

Answer (score 1):

GetURL actions may not work when testing locally, due to security sandbox restrictions. You have to test your HTML file from a server such as

```
http://localhost
```

or upload with FTP to a webserver somewhere.