# Created a hyperlink on a button however it only work on the first click then stop working

Tags: html, flash, hyperlink, actionscript-2

I'm new to flash. I am using Adobe Flash Professional CS6. I have created a menu bar with a drop down menu and rollovers to change the colors.

I have put the the code (below) on the background and then given the button the instance name of 'navbarbtnhome'.

`navbarbtnhome.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("http://www.google.com", "_self");}`

After i publish and open the HTML file the hyperlink will only work for the first click, after that I have to amend the code in some way and then publish and open it again, then the hyperlink will work another time until I repeat the process. Can anyone help, I'm totally lost for ideas now after trying for hours. my full menu bar is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/butktezqd6p4qn1/Home%20menu%20-%20Large.fla) if anyone wants to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though getURL doesn't work when testing your file locally, due to security sandbox restrictions. Assume that the links work, and upload it to your server and then test it -- hopefully it will work that way :)

Source: [getURL not working on HTML export (Actionscript2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879798/geturl-not-working-on-html-export-actionscript2-0)